# Change value of variable in pl/sql

Tags: date, if-statement, plsql, scripting

I am running a unix *_sh script but with methods that use pl/sql in it.

Method in the script:

```
method(){

sqlplus -s ${DB_CONNECTION} << EOF
set echo on;
set timing on;
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
      v_monthNow Date:=to_date('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
      v_charMonthNow Varchar(5):=to_char(v_monthNow,'MM');
      v_charMonthBefore Varchar(5) :=to_char(v_monthNow, 'MM')-1;

BEGIN
      dbms_output.Put_line('SYSDATE is '|| v_monthNow ||' || MonthNow is '|| v_charMonthNow);
      IF v_charMonthBefore = '0'
           set v_charMonthBefore = '12'
           dbms_output.Put_line('MonthBefore is '|| v_charMonthBefore);
      ELSE
           dbms_output.Put_line('MonthBefore is '|| v_charMonthBefore);

END;
/
EOF
}
```

My question is: how do I set value of v_charMonthBefore to what I want?

Actually if `sysdate` is `Jan 2018`, i need `v_monthNow=1` and `v_charMonthBefore=12`

if `sysdate` is `Feb 2018`, i need `v_monthNow=2` and `v_charMonthBefore=1`

Other way to do this is not required, i just need to fix what i have now as i am not really familiar with pl/sql.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CASE to detect the correct value.

My CTE is here just to create all 12 months in a year. You need lines 7 - 10.

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select to_number(to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1), 'mm')) mon
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 12
  5    )
  6  select
  7    mon as v_month_now,
  8    case when mon = 1 then 12
  9         else mon - 1
 10    end as v_month_before
 11  from test;

V_MONTH_NOW V_MONTH_BEFORE
----------- --------------
          1             12
          2              1
          3              2
          4              3
          5              4
          6              5
          7              6
          8              7
          9              8
         10              9
         11             10
         12             11

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```